# Why a tree structure takes more space than a sum of it's nodes

Tags: c++

Populating the following n-ary tree data structure creates 64'570'080 nodes, which should take ~1480mb of memory space (24 byte per node for x64 build). But the actual memory footprint of the program is ~1900mb (as both Visual Studio and the task manager indicate). When I don't populate a tree, but push the same amount of nodes into a vector, the footprint is ~1480mb as expected.

Why the tree takes more space than the same amount of nodes in a vector and how can I fix it? I use the latest MSVC compiler.

```cpp
struct Node
{
public:
    void AddChild()
    {
        if (first_child_ == nullptr)
        {
            first_child_ = std::make_unique<Node>();
            first_child_->parent_ = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Node* next = first_child_.get();
            while (next->next_sibling_ != nullptr)
            {
                next = next->next_sibling_.get();
            }
            next->next_sibling_ = std::make_unique<Node>();
            next->next_sibling_->parent_ = this;
        }
    }

    class NodeRange;
    NodeRange GetChildren();

    Node* GetNextSibling() { return next_sibling_.get(); }

private:
    // Pointer to the parent node. nullptr for the root.
    Node* parent_ = nullptr;

    // Pointer to the first child. nullptr for a leaf node.
    std::unique_ptr<Node> first_child_;

    // Pointer to the next sibling. nullptr if there are no further siblings.
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next_sibling_;
};

class NodeIterator 
    {
    public:
        NodeIterator(Node* node) : node_(node) {}
        Node* operator*() { return node_; }
        Node* operator->() { return node_; }
        bool operator==(NodeIterator& other) { return node_ == other.node_; }
        bool operator!=(NodeIterator& other) { return node_ != other.node_; }
        void operator++() { node_ = node_->GetNextSibling(); }

    private:
        Node* node_;
    };

    class Node::NodeRange 
    {
    public:
        NodeIterator begin() { return NodeIterator(node_); }
        NodeIterator end() { return NodeIterator(nullptr); }

    private:
        NodeRange(Node* node) : node_(node) {}
        Node* node_;
        friend class Node;
    };

Node::NodeRange Node::GetChildren() { return first_child_.get(); }
```

```cpp
#define MAX_DEPTH 16
#define BRANCHING_FACTOR 3

std::unique_ptr<Node> tree;
size_t nodeCount = 0;

void Populate(Node& node, int currentDepth = 0)
{
    if (currentDepth == MAX_DEPTH) return;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < BRANCHING_FACTOR; i++)
    {
        node.AddChild();
        nodeCount++;
    }

    for (Node* child : node.GetChildren())
    {
        Populate(*child, currentDepth + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    tree = std::make_unique<Node>();
    Populate(*tree.get());

    std::cout << "Nodes: " << nodeCount << "\n";
    std::cout << "Node size: " << sizeof(Node) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Estimated tree size, bytes: " << (nodeCount * sizeof(Node)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Estimated tree size, mb: " << (nodeCount * sizeof(Node) / 1024.0 / 1024.0) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since each tree node is allocated separately, there is an overhead to each heap memory allocation, the heap allocator stores its housekeeping information along with each allocated block. On a 64-bit system that overhead is 8 bytes for GNU malloc, MSVC run-time library may have a different non-zero overhead (but it looks to be 8 bytes as well). See [MallocInternals](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals) for more details.

---

One way to minimize the overhead is to allocate the tree nodes from a large pre-allocated array. An example is [boost::pool](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.pool).

---

Using `std::unique_ptr` for storing child nodes may cause stack overflow due to recursive calls: `~Node()` invokes `first_child_->~std::unique_ptr<Node>()` which invokes `~Node()`, which invokes `first_child_->~std::unique_ptr<Node>()` and so on, which may overflow the stack.

One solution is for `first_child_` and `next_sibling_` to be plain `Node*` pointers, and implement class `Tree` and code in `~Tree()` that walks the tree without recursion and destroys tree nodes manually. In this case `Tree` owns its `Node`s.

Comment: The last paragraph might be extended with the information, that his does not mean that `unique_ptr` are wrong in that case, but that it requires to write a destructor that takes care of it.

Comment: As already suggested, please extend the recursive destruction problem in container implementation and proposed solutions in your post please.

Comment: @Red.Wave I don‘t think that an implementation of that is required, as that has nothing to do with the asked question which is about explaining the difference in memory usage. It is just importation to mention that using `unique_ptr` in that case isn’t wrong, but requires the implementation of a destructor that takes care of that.

Comment: @t.niese If somebody asks such a question about heap, he most probably has difficulty with stack too. But in case he doesn't know what to ask, it doesn't mean we shouldn't mention what's appropriate. I am not good at composing replies; but IMHO since your reply is the accepted and only answer - which happens to be a very good reply too, it is worth to be perfect.

Comment: `A robost solution is for first_child_ and next_sibling_ to be plain Node*` that is a horrible advice, why throw away the benefits of `unqiue_ptr` in _"favour"_ of manual memory managment. `that walks the tree without recursion and destroys tree nodes manually.` that's true, but that can be done in the same way with `unqiue_ptr`, and you don't have to do manual memory management.

Comment: @t.niese You sound like an expert in this problem, please share your solution.